# Contigious subarrays function javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I created a JavaScript function that extracts all the contigious sub-arrays of an array and returns them in another Array
Here is the code

```
function contigious_sub_array (arr) {
    var output = [], worker = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        worker = [];
        output.push(arr[i]);    // On ajoute la première val
        var chien = arr[i];
        worker.push(chien); // Tableau worker qui va contenir la première val + les suivantes

        for (var j = (i + 1); j < arr.length; j++) {
            worker.push(arr[j]);
            output.push(worker);
        };
        worker = [];
    };
    return output;
}
```

However, when I do `console.log(contigious_sub_array([1, 2, 3]))`, 
I don't get the expected results, index 1 have as value `[1, 2, 3]` when it should be `[1, 2]`
What can be problem here?

Comment: I don't understand what your function is trying to do. Can we have more explanation ?

Comment: provide complete output you expect from input [1,2,3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues that might be causing a problem.  First, you push the `worker` array to the `output` array; this only pushes a reference to the former onto the later, so then when you modify the `worker` again that change is reflected in multiple entries of your `output` array.

Second, your two loops combine to iterate over the whole length of the input array, so you will end up with one entry in `output` being the same as the input `arr`.

You can solve the former issue by using `.slice()` to create a copy of the array - note that it only creates a shallow copy, so this wouldn't work if your array contained objects rather than numbers.

You can solve the latter by incorporating a check to exclude from `output` the array if it's length is the same as the input array.  This code is also somewhat simplified:

```
function contigious_sub_array (arr) {
  var output = [], worker = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      worker = [];

      for (var j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
          worker.push(arr[j]);
          if (worker.length != arr.length) {
            output.push(worker.slice());
          }
      };

  };
  return output;
}
```

Example output:

[image]

Note: this assumes that you don't want an entry in `output` corresponding to `[1, 2]` and also another entry corresponding to `[2, 1]`

Comment: Thank you soo much it really helped :D Never i would expect that. By the way, it's no use to add the if condition, [1, 2, 3] is considered a contigious subarray of [1,2, 3], as most websites do apparently say

Comment: Of course, if you want all the subarrays then just remove that `if` - in terminology parallel to set theory it depends whether you want all the subarrays or all the proper subarrays.

Comment: Can i add some extra question ?
I chrome's console, how did you get it to display the arrays like that ? I only have some sort of arrow

Comment: If you click the arrow it expands to reveal the contents of each object.